# Magento Integration with ERP

Tags: php, magento, csv

I have a customer in Greece with a custom ERP System. He have Magento 1.8 edition and needs to import from CSV or XML file the simple products with several attributes (plus auto-creating the corresponding configurable products) as well to assign them in multi-level categories. Also, he needs to export the orders and customers info to CSV or XML files, using them from ERP System. The Magmi extension is still available and the right solution for Magento CE 1.8 edition? Is there any other extension that you can use instead of Magmi? Is it possible using any extension to Chron the import/export process in order to synchronize the ERP/Magento updates in real-time ?

Answer (score 0):

Magmi will be a band-aid for work flows that needs a full integration.  Possible resolutions are mapping the data  through a linked server or creating SSIS integrations to pass data back and forth between MySQL and MSSQL.  Difficulties that will arise are modifying the integration according to the user requirements and updating magento versions with your user's database.